# How to return result values from node_redis function

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to return the **replies** from this function and use the replies in other function. I am newbie to NodeJs and trying to figure out a simple solution.

```
    var getKeys = function(key){
      var addkey = key + '*'
      myClient.keys(addkey, function (err, replies) {
        console.log(replies);
      });
    }
```

Question 2:

Is there a way to take variable inside the node_redis function?

Example:
redis_get -> Defined function for getting values

```
thingsUUID[i] = thingsUUIDKey[i].split("_").pop()
      redis_get("key", function(redis_items) {
        console.log(thingsUUID[i]);
});
```

Inside redis_get thingsUUID is undefined. I want to concatenate the thingsUUID and the result redis_items

Answer (score 2):

you could add the callback that is used in the `myClient.keys` function to your `getKeys` function like this:

```js
var getKeys = function(key, callback){
    var addkey = key + '*'
    myClient.keys(addkey, callback);
}

getKeys("EXAMPLE_KEY",  function (err, replies) {

    if (err) console.error(err);

    console.log(replies);
});
```

As `myClient.keys` requires a callback it is async and you can't return the response of this back into a value.

This is a good resource to get an overview about how callbacks work:
https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks

Comment: Thanks @driedel. Is it possible for you to give solution for Question 2?. I edited and added the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but if your variable `thinksUUID` is defined outside `redis_get` it should be accessible inside the callback:

```js
var thinksUUID = [1,2,3,4];

var getKeys = function(key, callback){
    var addkey = key + '*'
     myClient.keys(addkey, callback);
}

getKeys("EXAMPLE_KEY",  function (err, replies) {

    if (err) console.error(err);

    replies.forEach(function(item, index){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(thinksUUID[index]);
    });
});
```

If you want to hand over the variable `thinksUUID` to your defined function `redis_get` you need to change your signature of `redis_get(key, callback)` to `redis_get(key, thinksUUID, callback)`

Answer (score 0):

```
// using Node.js >= v8 built-in utility
const { promisify } = require('util');
// forcing function to return promise
const getAsync = promisify(redisClient.get).bind(redisClient);
const value = await getAsync(key);
console.log('value of redis key', value)
```